# OTEL Collector not receiving the logs with loki when exporting from .net 6 application

Tags: grafana, open-telemetry, grafana-loki, open-telemetry-collector, otel

OTLP Endpoint not receiving the logs when we export it from .NET 6 application. But it is exporting to console.

Here is the GitHub link for sample .NET application that we cloned and tried locally by adding references to open telemetry libraries

https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet/tree/main/examples/AspNetCore

[Open telemetry libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zE2ps.png)

1. Here is the **otel config.yaml** file

```
receivers:
otlp:
protocols:
  grpc:
  http:

processors:
batch:

exporters:
loki:
endpoint: "http://loki:3100/loki/api/v1/push"
tls:
  insecure: true
otlp:
endpoint: tempo:4317
tls:
  insecure: true
prometheus:
endpoint: "0.0.0.0:8889"
file:
path: /tmp/foo 

extensions:
health_check:
pprof:
zpages: 

service:
extensions: [health_check, pprof, zpages]
telemetry:
logs:
  level: "debug"
pipelines:
traces:
  receivers: [otlp]
  processors: [batch]
  exporters: [otlp]
logs:
  receivers: [otlp]
#      processors: [batch]
  exporters: [loki,file]
metrics:
  receivers: [otlp]
  processors: [batch]
  exporters: [prometheus]
```

2. **Here is the loki-config.Yaml**

```
auth_enabled: false

server:
  http_listen_port: 3100
  grpc_listen_port: 9096

common:
  path_prefix: /loki
  storage:
    filesystem:
      chunks_directory: /loki/chunks
      rules_directory: /loki/rules
  replication_factor: 1
  ring:
    instance_addr: 127.0.0.1
    kvstore:
      store: inmemory

query_range:
  results_cache:
    cache:
      embedded_cache:
        enabled: true
        max_size_mb: 100

schema_config:
  configs:
    - from: 2020-10-24
      store: boltdb-shipper
      object_store: filesystem
      schema: v11
      index:
        prefix: index_
        period: 24h

ruler:
  alertmanager_url: <http://localhost:9093>

analytics:
  reporting_enabled: false
```

3. Here is the **docker-compose.yml** file

```
version: '3'

services:
  loki:
    image: grafana/loki:2.7.0
    container_name: loki
    user: "5002"
    ports:
      - "3100:3100"
    volumes:
      - "/mnt/shared/loki/data:/loki"
      - "/mnt/shared/loki/config:/etc/loki"
    command: -config.file=/etc/loki/loki-config.yaml
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
    - observability 

  tempo:
    image: grafana/tempo:latest
    container_name: tempo
    user: "5002"
    command: [ "-config.file=/etc/tempo.yaml" ]
    volumes:
      - "/mnt/shared/tempo/config:/etc"
      - "/mnt/shared/tempo/data:/tmp/tempo"
    ports:
      - "14268:14268"  # jaeger ingest. If we are doing otlp, we don't need it
      - "3200:3200"   # tempo. Need it for Grafana
      - "4317:4317"   # otlp grpc
      - "4318:4318"   # otlp http
      - "9411"   # zipkin. If we are doing otlp, we don't need it
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
    - observability

  otel-collector:
    container_name: otel-collector
    image: otel/opentelemetry-collector-contrib:0.86.0
    user: "5002"    
    command: [ "--config=/etc/otel-collector-config.yaml" ]
    volumes:
      - /mnt/shared/opentemetry/opentelemetry-collector/config:/etc
      - /tmp/disco:/tmp
    environment:     
      LOKI_ENDPOINT: "http://loki:3100/loki/api/v1/push"
    networks:
    - observability

    restart: unless-stopped

networks:
    observability:
        external: true
```

Let us know if we are missing anything with respective to .net application or with respective to docker or loki or otel config yaml files.

Any solution for this scenario?